# Not able to add CM in Content Porter

Tags: content-porter-2013

I am getting this error "could not find sdl tridion content manager server (server name) please verify that the server is up and running.

I have ensured the below after going through this [url](http://sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/tutorials/using-content-porter-2009-sp1-for-dtap-5.aspx) . I have tried with restarting the relevant services as well.

Could anyone through some light on this ?

Comment: can you reach the CM server through the URL you configured in the CP server dialog? Please note you selected the right protocol and port and that the name is a fully qualified domain name. If you can reach the CM from the location you are running CP, then when the CP connection fails, are there any connection errors logged in the Tridion event log on the CM server? Also can you edit your question and add teh details of which services you deemed relevant to restart exactly?

Comment: Maybe you can try running it from the server itself to see if it's a ports issue...

Comment: Thanks Bart and robrtc. Issue has been resolved. The issue was spelling mistake in my name in CMS user :-)